# Error in order and the cosine distance in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I am trying to run KNN on a dataset. I am using the predict function from the rectools package. I am running into a weird error while using the order function on the output of the distance function aka cosine. Here is the error

```
Error in order(cosines, decreasing = FALSE) : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
```

The code related to the error is following.

```
onecos <- function(y) 
  {
    cosDist(newData ,y, wtcovs=NULL,wtcats=NULL)
  }
  cosines <- sapply(origDataRatedNI ,onecos)
 #cosines <- sapply(cosines, unlist)

  findKnghbourRtng <- function(ki)
  {
    ki <- min(ki, length(cosines))
    # nearby is a vector containing the indices of the ki closest neighbours
    nearby <- cosines[order(cosines, decreasing=FALSE)[1:ki]]
    mean(as.numeric(found[2, nearby]))
  }
  sapply(k, findKnghbourRtng)
```

I have tried unlisting it and feeding it to the function but that is not working either. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, your example is not reproducible because we don't have access to your data. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example

Comment: If you manually run your function, does `cosines[order(cosines, decreasing=FALSE)[1:ki]]` return a reasonable result?